# Must-read C++ documents for "under the hood" performance understanding?

Tags: c++, performance, architecture, latency

In order to understand exactly what happens "under the hood" when writing C++ what documents would you recommend?

So far I have:

- GNU C++ compiler documentation (I thought this would be good to see what actually happens)
- C++ ABI(?) specification

Books:

- Inside the C++ Object Model
- Meyers' Effective Series

Comment: Once again another useful post relating to programming is closed, yet I would be permitted to ask a silly question like why while(false) never loops....

Comment: That's because this is a QA site, with exactly one accepted answer. It is unfortunately not a wiki.

Answer (score 1):

For the real under-the-hood understand you should be familiar with the G++ source code. The compiler code will tell you a lot about the language.

For a lower level understanding, you should be familiar with latest C++ Standard (C++11).

Comment: For your first comment do you mean checking the ASM output say, from visual studio?

Comment: @mezamorphic, ASM output will not never give you the complete under-the-hood understanding of the Language. The best of the compilers only  use less than 50% of the available machine instruction-set. It is only be understanding the compiler code, we can be sure of under-the-hood workings.

Answer (score 1):

Use compilation to assembler: `g++ -fverbose-asm -S` in the case of GCC, and kindred switches in other compilers. That's as close to 'under the hood' as it gets.

Comment: The best of the compilers are able to utilize less than 50% of the machine-instruction-set. So analyzing the ASM output will not even take you to the half-way mark of the understanding.

Comment: machine-instruction-set != under-the-hood; Predictive branching, unrolling, various optimizations matter more than weird processor-specific instructions

Comment: I will say that you do not know what you are talking about "In computer architecture, a branch predictor is a digital circuit that tries to guess which way a branch (e.g. an if-then-else structure) will go before this is known for sure. The purpose of the branch predictor is to improve the flow in the instruction pipeline. Branch predictors are crucial in today's pipelined microprocessors for achieving high performance." The compiler had to inject specifid machine instruction only then the processor can do anything...

Answer (score 1):

I learned by first learning the x86 assembly instruction set and instruction clock timings.  Once you know this, you know what the compiler is actually converting your code into, and you get an idea of what it can and cannot do.  From there, if I were interested in a particular piece of code, I'd get the assembler output from the compiler and experiment with various ways of coding it.  Over the years, I've found a few things... 1) compilers are pretty good at optimizing, often even with coding something several different ways ending up with identical assembly output, 2) I'm often surprised at how much inlining a compiler does, and 3) I'm often surprised about how sometimes a tiny little bit of C++ code results in a huge amount of assembly output.  So when you're copying multiple inheritance C++ objects you'll realize how expensive that is, and when you're writing little utility methods to protect object data you'll realize how in-expensive that tool can be.  Happy hunting.